# Cant put objects or strings into javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've been trying for hours to get this code to work. As of right now it finds the number of anchors I then have an array set up. An undetermined size array. Inside the for loop it takes the anchor and goes to get the .href. I've seen this work as I've put alerts down right after this code.

My problem comes when I try to put it into an array. I want the .href put into the array, but doesn't work. I've tested it with numbers, number of links (anchors), but it just does not seem to work when I try to put in the .href links.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Oi</h2>
<p>Java output</p>
<a href="#" onclick="showName()">cat buns</a>
```

In the body is a bunch of divs that contain links. 
ex:

```
<div>
<a href="active.url" ><img></img></a>
</div>
```

---

JavaScript

```
function showName() {
     var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
     var aryTest12 = new Array();

    for (i=1; i<=links.length; i++){

               aryTest12[i].push(links[i].href);

    }
     alert(aryTest12);

            }
```

I've tried aryTest12[i]=links[i].href;

I've tried converting links[i].href into a string and putting them into the array with another for loop, but nothing I do seems to work. Terribly sorry if this is ugly, I tried to make this look as pretty as possible. I can't use Jquery. Thanks in advance. I know this is basic stuff but I've looked all over google and stackoverflow, but haven't come across anything that's worked.

Comment: You can use [`document.links`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#dom-document-links) to get all the links. And the loop should start from `0`, not `1`, the condition should be `i < links.length`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what I think you're trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/UtYNV/

HTML

```
<a href="#1" onclick="showName()">cat buns1</a>
<a href="#2" onclick="showName()">cat buns2</a>
<a href="#3" onclick="showName()">cat buns3</a>
<a href="#4" onclick="showName()">cat buns4</a>
```

JS

```
function showName() {

     var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
     var aryTest12 = [];

    for (i=0; i<links.length; i++){
      aryTest12.push(links[i].href);
    }
    alert(aryTest12);
}
```

Notice the `push` call on the array.

Comment: Thank you sir! Was it because I started the array wrong? Why is it that var aryTest12 = new Array(); didn't work?

Regardless, thank you.

Comment: Its essentially the same thing, just a short hand version